# finding the cumulative number of unique values

Tags: pandas

I a Pandas DF that among other columns has a date column and an IDs column.  I need to group/sort this data by date and for each date calculate the number of unique IDs seen since the first row (start of the timeline).  Is there a way to do this using pandas/numpy without writing out a loop?

Comment: what about counting unique IDs,and then applying "cumsum"?

Comment: if you would provide sample input data and expected output we could provide you working example ;)

Comment: the number of total unique IDs seen up to a given day is not the same as the sum of unique IDs seen on each day.  In other words,`U(Dn) != U(D1)+U(D2)+U(D3)+...+D(n)`.

Comment: I would try to solve it if there would be clear sample of input data and expected output. Good luck to all those who like to guess what OP wants!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look into pandas.unique:

```
import pandas as pd
for date in pd.unique(df['Date']):
    unique_ids = pd.unique(df[df['Date']==date]['id'])
    print len(unique_ids)
```

**Edit:** 2nd try

```
newdf = df[['Date', 'id']].drop_duplicates()
newdf.groupby('Date').count()
```

Comment: as I asked: is there is a way to do this without writing out a loop

Comment: Yep, that worked with one modification: specifying the column in a call to drop_duplicates.  So the final line is this:  `df[['date','id']].drop_duplicates(['id']).groupby('date').count().cumsum()`

Comment: Nice answer. IINM, it relies on the items being sorted by date, though, so it requires  sorting if not.

Comment: I do not understand why this does not 'double dip'. A value might occur uniquely at one date and then again uniquely at another, and so the cumsum would count it twice. No?

Answer (score 3):

at least now it's clear what OP wants...

```
print(df.groupby('date').id.nunique().cumsum())
```

Test data set:

```
date;id
2012-03-31;111
2012-03-31;2
2012-03-31;1
2012-03-31;4
2012-04-01;15
2012-04-01;6
2012-04-01;7
2012-04-01;118
2012-04-01;9
2012-05-01;10
2012-05-01;11
```

Comparison of two different approaches:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=';').sort('date')


print(df[['date','id']].drop_duplicates(['id']).groupby('date').count().cumsum())
print(df.groupby('date').id.nunique().cumsum())
```

Output:

```
            id
date
2012-03-31   4
2012-04-01   9
2012-05-01  11
date
2012-03-31     4
2012-04-01     9
2012-05-01    11
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

PS so it does return correct result. At least for that data set. That is why it's important to provide test data set and expected output!

PPS another interesting observation:

```
from timeit import Timer
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=';', parse_dates=['date']).sort_values(['date'])

def drop_dups():
    df[['date','id']].drop_duplicates(['id']).groupby('date').count().cumsum()

def nunique():
    df.groupby('date').id.nunique().cumsum()


print('drop_dups():\t{:.6f}'.format(Timer(drop_dups).timeit(1000)))
print('nunique():\t{:.6f}'.format(Timer(nunique).timeit(1000)))
```

Output:

```
drop_dups():    6.722572
nunique():      1.512233
```

Comment: No, this doesn't return the right result.  And I already explained why in the comment to you under the question.

Comment: @DmitryB., yes it does. I've updated my answer with the prove. Thanks for downvoting!

Comment: You are making an assumption I never stated: that IDs are always increasing.  Perhaps I should've provided data, but the lack of didn't stop the right answer from being given.

Comment: @DmitryB., i've updated my answer with different data set where ID's aren't always increasing - got again the same result for both approaches. What am i doing wrong this time? ;)

Comment: @DmitryB. maybe you can provide a small data set against which i would get different result set?

Comment: I had never seen nuinique before. Faster too? Cool!

Answer (score 1):

I coded the following snippet since the rest of the answers didn't solve my issue.

So this snippet will number of unique ids up to the latest week from the beginning on each iteration. The above answers gave me a cumulative sum of these unique id thereby causing mismatches.

ex: for the following input:

> week          id
> 2020-12-04    101
> 2020-12-04    102
> 2020-12-11    101
> 2020-12-11    103

output for other codes mentioned here:

> 2020-12-04 : 2
> 2020-12-11 : 4

my desired output was:

> 2020-12-04 : 2
> 2020-12-11 : 3

And the code snippet for this is:

```
for date in pd.unique(df['week']):
       print(date,"\t",df[df['week']<=date].id.nunique())
```

I am not sure if OP wanted this same output, but this will help just incase if someone needs the output in the way I mentioned

Answer (score 1):

[@MaxU's analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35759687/3025856) is based on a test data set in which no IDs ever reappear in later dates. In this special case, both approaches do indeed yield identical results.

More generally—and for the problem I was trying to solve—IDs may appear on multiple dates. Consider this modified test data set:

```
date;id
2012-03-31;111
2012-03-31;2
2012-03-31;1
2012-03-31;4
2012-04-01;15
2012-04-01;2 #<-- Here 2 is seen again
2012-04-01;7
2012-04-01;118
2012-04-01;9
2012-05-01;2 #<-- Here 2 is seen yet again
2012-05-01;11
```

In this case, we would expect the following result:

```
            id
date
2012-03-31   4 #<-- IDs seen so far: 111, 2, 1, 4
2012-04-01   8 #<-- IDs seen so far: 111, 2, 1, 4, 15, 7, 118, 9
2012-05-01   9 #<-- IDs seen so far: 111, 2, 1, 4, 15, 7, 118, 9, 11 (all of them)
```

MaxU's `nunique()` approach instead returns:

```
            id
date
2012-03-31   4 #<-- Distinct count of IDs on this date
2012-04-01   9 #<-- Value of prior row (4), plus distinct count of IDs on this date (5)
2012-05-01   11 #<-- Value of prior row (9), plus disctint count of IDs on this date (2)
```

The solutions posted that first apply `drop_duplicates()` do indeed return the correct result. My final working code is:

```
df[['date','id']].drop_duplicates(['id']).groupby('date').count().cumsum()
```

Comment: Generally, if you don't have the reputation to comment, you shouldn't post your comment as an answer. In this case, however, I think this clearly goes beyond just a comment, and adds value to the thread. As it's ultimately reaffirming other approaches, it's a borderline case, but I think your useful explanation salvages it as a unique contribution.