# Cumulative count of unique values in pandas

Tags: pandas

I would like to cumulatively count unique values from a column in a pandas frame by week. For example, imagine that I have data like this:

```python
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'week':[1,1,2,1,2,2],'module_id':['A','B','A','A','B','C']})
```

```
+---+---------+------+-----------+
|   | user_id | week | module_id |
+---+---------+------+-----------+
| 0 |       1 |    1 |         A |
| 1 |       1 |    1 |         B |
| 2 |       1 |    2 |         A |
| 3 |       2 |    1 |         A |
| 4 |       2 |    2 |         B |
| 5 |       2 |    2 |         C |
+---+---------+------+-----------+
```

What I want is a running count of the number of unique module_ids up to each week, i.e. something like this:

```
+---+---------+------+-------------------------+
|   | user_id | week | cumulative_module_count |
+---+---------+------+-------------------------+
| 0 |       1 |    1 |                       2 |
| 1 |       1 |    2 |                       2 |
| 2 |       2 |    1 |                       1 |
| 3 |       2 |    2 |                       3 |
+---+---------+------+-------------------------+
```

It is straightforward to do this as a loop, for example this works:

```
running_tally = {}
result = {}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['user_id'] not in running_tally:
        running_tally[row['user_id']] = set()
        result[row['user_id']] = {}
    running_tally[row['user_id']].add(row['module_id'])
    result[row['user_id']][row['week']] = len(running_tally[row['user_id']])
print(result)
```

```
{1: {1: 2, 2: 2}, 2: {1: 1, 2: 3}}
```

But my real data frame is enormous and so I would like a vectorised algorithm instead of a loop.

There's a similar sounding question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35759120/575530), but looking at the accepted answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35759315/575530)) the original poster does not want uniqueness across dates cumulatively, as I do.

How would I do this vectorised in pandas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Idea is create `list`s per groups by both columns and then use `np.cumsum` for cumulative lists, last convert values to sets and get length:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['user_id','week'])['module_id']
         .apply(list)
         .groupby(level=0)
         .apply(np.cumsum)
         .apply(lambda x: len(set(x)))
         .reset_index(name='cumulative_module_count'))

print (df1)
   user_id  week  cumulative_module_count
0        1     1                        2
1        1     2                        2
2        2     1                        1
3        2     2                        3
```

Comment: Wow, there are so many things you have used in that answer that I have never seen and do not know how to use :( But thanks, I will work my way through that.

Comment: @dumbledad - not sure about performance, because pandas better working with scalars like lists, the best test with real data.

Comment: Yes, on the real data it's taking 19 minutes to run. Could be worse though!

Answer (score 1):

[Jezrael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57055945/6704717) can be slightly improved by using `pipe` instead of `apply(list)`, which should be faster, and then using `np.unique` instead of the trick with `np.cumsum`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['user_id', 'week']).pipe(lambda x: x.apply(np.unique))        
                                      .groupby('user_id')
                                      .apply(np.cumsum)
                                      .apply(np.sum)
                                      .apply(lambda x: len(set(x)))
                                      .rename('cumulated_module_count')
                                      .reset_index(drop=False))

print(df1)
   user_id  week  cumulated_module_count
0        1     1                       2
1        1     2                       2
2        2     1                       1
3        2     2                       3
```

Comment: I think you mean `np.unique` rather than `np.nunique` (which errors) and that added column is not the results I wanted, e.g. the value for user_id = 1 and week = 2 should be 2 but your code has it as 1

Comment: @dumbledad Ok I did not get that you wanted to sum over weeks ascending. I will modify accordingly. One more step is needed.

Comment: The point is that storing lists as values in pandas is discouraged.

Comment: That works. I'll report back on timing information tomorrow. One question: why is `.pipe(lambda x: x.apply(np.unique))` faster than`.apply(np.unique)` (they give the same output on my data)?

Comment: Also when you say "then using np.unique instead of the trick with np.cumsum" you are actually using both nunique and the cumsum trick, no?

Comment: I cannot get your version to work on the real data, though it works fine on the test data I provided in the question. The `cumsum` gives the error _operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (6,) _ If I can work out how to phrase it, I'll post a follow-up question

Comment: You're right, I'll edit this according to your observations

Comment: Are all module ids strings ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196578/discussion-between-sebk-and-dumbledad).