# Pandas groupby count unique non cumulative

Tags: python, pandas, count, cumulative-sum

I have this toy data set

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'user':['John','Steve','Steve','Steve','Jane','Jane','Jane','Jane','Alice','Alice','Alice'],
                  'days':[1,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3]})
```

yielding

```
user  days
John    1
Steve   1
Steve   2
Steve   3
Jane    1
Jane    2
Jane    3
Jane    4
Alice   1
Alice   2
Alice   3
```

I wish to count the exact number of user with only 1 days, only 2 and only 3 days.

Desired output

```
user   days_count
1           1
3           2
4           1
```

I have tried code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554920/pandas-aggregate-count-distinct) and from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35759120/finding-the-cumulative-number-of-unique-values), but non yielded above (or similar result)

Comment: For clarity, can you break down the calculation of `1`/`2`/`1`?

Comment: @mozway one user came 1 day, two users came 3 days and 1 user came 4 days.

Comment: thank you, this is what I had understood (and my answer does that), I asked for future readers to make sure that the logic is explicit.

Comment: Btw, be aware that the accepted answer only works if the rows are sorted by increasing day and all days are numbered correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a double [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df['user'].value_counts(sort=False).value_counts(sort=False)
```

Output:

```
count
1    1
3    2
4    1
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

For the exact format:

```
out = (df['user'].value_counts(sort=False)
       .value_counts(sort=False)
       .rename_axis('user')
       .reset_index(name='days_count')
      )
```

Or:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(Counter(df['user']).values())

out = pd.DataFrame({'user': c.keys(), 'day_count': c.values()})
```

Output:

```
   user  days_count
0     1           1
1     3           2
2     4           1
```

Answer (score 2):

There will be many ways to do this, one way for your dataset is:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='user', keep='last').groupby('candies').count()
```

Output:

```
        user
candies      
1           1
3           2
4           1
```